# same pointer gives different address when it is printed with another pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
      int a[]={10,20,30,40,50};

      int *b,**c,*d;

      cout<<a<<endl;    ..............(1)

      cout<<b;          ..............(2)

      return 1;
}
```

If i run this program containing only (1) marked statement output is

0x22fecc

but if i run the program with both statements i.e (1) and (2)
then the output is

0x22fec8
0x401d2e

Q1 : why different value printed for a in 2 cases

Q2 : what if i do b = a  and then print b  and a ?

Q3 : why b and a give same address of themselves in Q2 ? Are they same now i.e they share same location ? does b is an alias of a now ?

Q4 : if i do b = a+1 and then cout<< b why it gives address of a ? it should have given the address of a+1 ?

```
 Is cout<<a  is equivalent to  cout<<&a ?
```

I am using codeblocks 13.12 on Win7 32bit .

Comment: It is undefined behaviour to print uninitialized `b`. Also, there is no reason the addresses should be the same each time you run the program.

Answer (score 1):

```
Q1 : why different value printed for a in 2 cases
```

The compiler is probably optimizing b out. Try setting optimizations to none on your compiler.

```
Q2 : what if i do b = a and then print b and a ?
```

Try it, let us know how it goes :)

```
Q3 : why b and a give same address of themselves in Q2 ? Are they same now i.e they share same location ? does b is an alias of a now ?
```

They're different, but point to the same location. Like two pieces of paper that both have your home address on them.

```
Q4 : if i do b = a+1 and then cout<< b why it gives address of a ? it should have given the address of a+1 ?
```

It does give the address of a+1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the same value for the both outputs then insert statement

```
b = a;
```

In expressions arrays are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements. Thus in the statement aboth expression a is converted to a pointer to its first element and is assigned to b.

In this statement

```
cout<<a<<endl;
```

a also is converted to a pointer to its first element. As result after assigning a to b

```
cout<<a<<endl;
```

and

```
cout<<b;
```

will output the same value.

After this statement

```
b = a+1
```

b will point to the second element (with index 1) of array a.

EDIT: Oh, I have understood your question. It seems that when variable b is not used in the function whrn the compiler simply removes it from the generated object code. When the variable b is used then the compiler allocates memory for it on the stack. So the address of a is changed depending on whether variable b is used or not.

Comment: i don't want b = a what i want to know is that why a is printed differently when only (1) was included a was printed as 0x22fecc and when i included (1) and (2) then a was printed as 0x22fec8 i don't care what b is printing ?

Comment: Because that was the second time you ran the program and it's not necessary for the address to be the same as the first time.